# Laptop Doesn't Suspend When Connected to External Monitor Mouse & Keyboard

Tags: suspend, 22.04, external-monitor

So I'm using 22.04 on a Dell Precision.
I've disabled suspend-on-lid-close via Gnome Tweaks, because I'm using the external monitor on it's own with keyboard/mouse.
Since doing this I can't seem to get the system to suspend even if I suspend it manually.
It seems like it attempts to do this, but instantly ends up back on the log-in screen.

Any ideas appreciated. I haven't seen anyone with this exact issue.

Comment: In your scenario all it takes is a slight movement of the mouse to wake it up.

Comment: Well I thought this might be the case, but even if I turn the mouse off it persists. 
This is a system suspend issue, and not related to the mouse waking it.